# Is there a simple way to have a GWT CellList with multiselection and check boxes

Tags: gwt

I'v got a lot of different lists of objects which I must provide to the user. The user has the possibility to select multiple elements in this lists. A check box in front of every item in the list is definitely needed.

It seams to me that the standard solution for this problem is a CellTable or a DataGrid but it is so very inconvenient to implement wit all the set-up stuff. Isn't there any simple solution like the ListBox where I got the possibility to enable the check box / multi-selection feature in just a few lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Within GWT Widgets**

### Option 1

```
ListBox -> Single & Multi Selection - No Checkbox.
```

### Option 2

```
CellTable/DataGrid -> Single & Multi Selection with Selection Checkbox.
```

### Option 3

```
CellList -> Single & Multi Selection & Customized Cells with CheckBox
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Are you able to show me the trick to use check boxes in CellList like you mentioned in option 3.

Comment: Did u reference - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells